# How to save a ReportLab Canvas as PNG image?

Tags: python, canvas, reportlab

I'm using reportlab to draw a PDF normaly used for printing. How can i save the canvas as a PNG image instead, without using additional binary tools to convert the generated pdf?

I assume i need to convert it to a reportlab Drawing, but don't see a way to do so.

```py
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
c = canvas.Canvas("form.pdf", pagesize=(100, 50))
c.drawString(20, 20, 'Example …')
c.save()  # but as image
```

Answer (score 1):

From the 'reportlab-userguide', I found a piece of code, not sure it is useful?

```
from reportlab.graphics import renderPM
d = Drawing(400, 200)
d.add(Rect(50, 50, 300, 100, fillColor=colors.yellow))
d.add(String(150, 100, 'Hello World', fontSize=18, fillColor=colors.red))
d.add(String(180, 86, 'Special characters \
\xc2\xa2\xc2\xa9\xc2\xae\xc2\xa3\xce\xb1\xce\xb2',
             fillColor=colors.red))
renderPM.drawToFile(d, 'example1.png', 'PNG')
```

Comment: If you are not sure, then why do you post it as an answer?

Comment: Because this is a method to sava PNG from reportlab, it can do same thing like which submiter wanted also.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but unfortunately this is how to save a Drawing (what is created on line 2 of your quoted code). I need this for a Canvas.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there're no functions in `reportlab` package to convert `Canvas` object to PNG image. But you can use another packages (f.e. [pdf2image](https://github.com/Belval/pdf2image)) to convert `Canvas` to PNG image.

**Installation**

To use `pdf2image` package you should install `poppler` and `pdf2image` packages. You can find installation instructions [here](https://github.com/Belval/pdf2image) (section "How to install")

After installation you can solve your problem using this approach:

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from pdf2image import convert_from_bytes

c = canvas.Canvas("form.pdf", pagesize=(100, 50))
c.drawString(20, 20, 'Example …')
image = convert_from_bytes(c.getpdfdata())[0]
image.save('form.png')
```

Comment: Thank you for this proposal, but pdf2image (better said poppler) is a huge binary dependency. Unfortunately I cannot control the environment where my applications runs so far. I will try to make this more clear in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I found the suggestion in [Yan Weitao's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58642641/4794) very helpful. Here's the equivalent of the example in your question:

```
from reportlab.graphics.renderPM import drawToFile
from reportlab.graphics.shapes import Drawing, String

drawing = Drawing(width=100, height=50)
drawing.contents.append(String(20, 20, 'Example …'))
drawToFile(drawing, 'example.png')
```

After digging into the `drawToFile()` function, I think you might be able to use the `reportlab.graphics.renderPM.PMCanvas` class instead of the standard canvas. It has a `saveToFile()` method, but my first attempt just generated a blank image, so you'll have to do some experimenting.